# Extract Hyperlinks Google Apps Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

For a long time the following code did work perfectly to extract hyperlinks from a text using regex-expression:

```
var text = "this is a http://google.de link!";
var link = text.match("(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$])", "gi");
```

The result should be "http://google.de" for the variable ***link***. But it doesn't work anymore. I deem Google has changed something in GAS!?

Can you please tell me, which expression I can use to extract hyperlinks from a string?

Comment: You should have been using `.match(/.../gi)` (no quotes)

Comment: Ditto.  I was going to say, it looks like swapping the A-Z bits for A-Za-z would probably fix it.  Or set case insensitive with the gi flag.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you guys....``var link = text.match(/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+üäö&@#/%=~_|$])/gi);``